# jackson deserialization issue in scala

Tags: scala, jackson

I have a trait and two case class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(Array(
  new Type(value = classOf[ScreenablePlainTextAddressValue], name = "ScreenablePlainTextAddressValue"),
  new Type(value = classOf[ScreenableAddressValue], name = "ScreenableAddressValue")))
trait ScreenableAddress {
  def screeningAddressType: String
  def addressFormat: String
}
@JsonTypeName(value = "ScreenablePlainTextAddressValue")
case class ScreenablePlainTextAddressValue(addressFormat: String, screeningAddressType: String,
                                           mailingAddress: MailingAddress) extends ScreenableAddress{
//code 
}

@JsonTypeName(value = "ScreenableAddressValue")
case class ScreenableAddressValue(addressFormat: String, screeningAddressType: String, value: String)
  extends ScreenableAddress{
//code
    }
```

I am trying to deserialize the a json using jackson mapper for the above classes and I get a error as below:

```
missing property 'type' that is to contain type id  (for class com.amazon.isp.execution.model.ScreenableAddress)
```

My Json look like this:

```
"{\"schemaVersion\":\"1.0\",\"screeningEntities\":[{\"screeningRecordList\":[{\"address\":{}},{\"address\":{\"addressFormat\":\"ADDRESS_ID\",\"value\":\"SK36SAV4WD4BSGDLGZQEG05RMMA0261533395I3IZ4AMMRVPXTQ2EIA2OXZFEHLF\",\"screeningAddressType\":\"OTHER_ADDRESS\"}},{\"name\":{}},{\"name\":{\"screeningNameType\":\"OTHER_NAME\",\"nameFormat\":\"KEYMASTER_SEALED_FULL_NAME\",\"value\":\"AAAAAAAAAADYzV1Zr7RxcB5y53pylNH4KgAAAAAAAAD3vya/1QtdPxVBZM+alrMIZZvaz9DHm+w+qby7z/c8YutbxeoX6so+mGY=\"}},{\"name\":{\"screeningNameType\":\"LEGAL_NAME\",\"nameFormat\":\"KEYMASTER_SEALED_FULL_NAME\",\"value\":\"AAAAAAAAAADYzV1Zr7RxcB5y53pylNH4KgAAAAAAAACRUkz7uKJGOQCB0pZWXRXTFrk9Enpucj33hV+/yHRM/dQKo2yWGxGcjB8=\"}}]}],\"screeningMetaData\":{\"customerId\":\"" + CustomerID + "\"}}"
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What does the JSON you are deserializing look like?

Comment: Added the Json in question description.

Comment: This doesn't look even close to JSON described by those annotations to me. Where is the `type` property (as the error message says)? Those names aren't used as values of any property at all. What are `\"address\":{}` and `\"name\":{}` supposed to correspond to? Etc.